# Firebase Auth API Key not valid when deployed in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, next.js, firebase-authentication

I'm using github actions to deploy a NextJS app to google app engine but when I try to login I get auth/api-key-not-valid.-please-pass-a-valid-api-key error in console. In localhost it works perfectly.
I already tried to print the key before initializing firebase and it shows it correctly.

What can it be?

[image: Console error]

**My Firebase configuration file:**

```js
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp, getApps, getApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, inMemoryPersistence, setPersistence } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

// Initialize Firebase
const firebase_app = getApps().length ? getApp() : initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const auth = getAuth(firebase_app);

setPersistence(auth, inMemoryPersistence);
export default firebase_app;
export { auth }
```

**My github action:**

```yaml
name: 'Deployment Dev'

on:
    pull_request: 
        branches: 
            - dev
    push:
        branches:
            - dev
    workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
    deploy:
        permissions: 
            contents: 'read'
            id-token: 'write'
        
        name: Deploy to App Engine
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            - name: Checkout
              uses: actions/checkout@v3
                
            - id: 'auth'
              uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v1'
              with:
                credentials_json: ${{secrets.GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE_KEY}}
            
            - name: 'Set up Cloud SDK'
              uses: 'google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v1'
            
            - name: 'Copy app.yaml'
              run: |
                gcloud storage cp gs://abacus-unified-env-config/dev/app-web.yaml app.yaml
            
            - name: 'Create secrets/firebase'
              run: |
                mkdir -p ./secrets
                echo '${{secrets.GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE_KEY}}' > ./secrets/serviceAccountKey.json
            
            - name: Google App Engine
              id: deploy
              uses: google-github-actions/deploy-appengine@v1.2.7
              with:
                flags: --no-cache
                build_env_vars: ${{secrets.DEV_ENV}}
                env_vars: ${{secrets.DEV_ENV}}
```